# solving system of equations by using the Gauss-Seidel method

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I'm having problem solving this system of equations:

\begin{array}{lcl}x & -3y & 100z & = & 123 \\ 200x & -3y & 2z & = & 765 \\ x & -500y & 2z & = & 987\end{array}

I'm supposed to find the solution to the system of equations with accuracy of $\epsilon=0.01$ using the Gauss-Seidel method. $(3.5;\;-2;\;1)$ is the starting point. Also, the convergence needs to be guaranteed. I will appreciate any help. I hope everything I wrote is understandable.

Comment: What is your question, more precisely ?

Comment: @Moo yes i am allowed to change the matrix

Comment: @YvesDaoust i am looking for x, y, z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [*Gauss-Seidel*](https://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/loci/joma/iterative-methods-for-solving-iaxi-ibi-gauss-seidel-method) Method requires the matrix to be in [*diagonally dominant*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonally_dominant_matrix) form.

This matrix is not diagonally dominant and G-S does not converge (sometimes it still may).

The first step is to put the matrix in D-D form so we have $Ax = b$ as

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}200 & -3 & 2 \\
 1 & -500 & 2 \\
 1 & -3 & 100 \\
\end{pmatrix}, b = \begin{pmatrix}765\\
 987 \\
 123 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

You can figure out how many iterations you need to meet your accuracy requirement

$$\begin{align}x_0 &= (3.5,-2,1)\\
x_1 &= (3.785,-1.96243,1.1332771)\\
x_2 &= (3.784230779,-1.96189843,1.133300739)\\
x_3 &= (3.784238516,-1.96189832,1.133300665)\\
x_4 &= (3.784238519,-1.96189832,1.133300665)\end{align}$$

The exact results are

$$x = \begin{pmatrix}
 \dfrac{900785}{238036} \\
 -\dfrac{3269017}{1666252} \\
 \dfrac{3776729}{3332504} \\
\end{pmatrix} \approx 
\begin{pmatrix}
3.784238518543414\\-1.961898320302091\\1.133300665205503 \end{pmatrix}$$